# Requesting advice/caveats on upgrading DOTS on Domino 9

Tags: osgi, lotus-domino

Currently in production we have Domino 8.5.3 running and a developed osgi dots tasklet running communicating with a JMS Queue.

We are about to upgrade the Domino platform to Domino 9 and I was wondering if there are any caveats or any general advice about the specific osgi dots tasklet I need to consider before upgrading?

*I have posted this in ServerFault as well for the server part and this question is to be considered for programming…*

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it works after upgrading to Domino 9